# How to play multiple sounds at once without reloading data?

Tags: javascript, html5, audio

I am making an HTML5 game, which involves one audio being played multiple times at once.

I searched this issue up and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654558/html5-js-play-same-sound-multiple-times-at-the-same-time

It seemed to help, except later a question came up:

If I do cloneNode(), will it copy the sound AND the currently loaded audio data, or will it have to reload the data?

Is there a better way to play multiple sounds while making sure no data needs to be reloaded?

Comment: Honestly I’d try it and see.

Comment: not helpful at all @bob

Comment: I’m not trying to be rude, I just mean what’s the harm in just trying it and seeing. You should be able to use the developer tools to debug and see whether it’s doing a reload (use the Network pane to see if the sound file is fetched a second time or not). Might be faster than waiting on an answer is all I was thinking. If that’s not the case then I retract my comment.

Comment: if I try I might have to rewrite my code

Comment: Yes, game development often includes rewriting code. I'd concur with bob that a great way to find the answer here is to construct a simple test and measure what you find. This will often be faster than waiting for a stranger to do the same thing and tell you what they found, or waiting even longer for a stranger who already knows the inner workings of cloneNode inside-out to happen to find your question.