# CloneNode or Audio Pool?

Tags: html5, audio

I have a game, but I have to make a decision about audio.

Should I preload an audio pool, or create cloneNode when played?

Which is better in terms of best loading and better performance?

Comment: What does your profiling tell you from the experiments you've doubtlessly been running to investigate [your previous question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/192376/39518)?

Comment: Well, it seems like it does work on chrome, but it seems like safari has a bit of a delay, and it's on my sisters phone, so connecting her phone to my Chromebook isn't an option @DMGregory.

Comment: It sounds like you've discovered a reason to prefer one over the other to minimize delay then. What do you need from us that you have not been able to determine from your tests?

Comment: Well could you test if safari (desktop AND mobile) reloads the cloneNode? @DMGregory